# Retain Position and Scale Values of Render Texture Canvas Elements to another Canvas

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, canvas, camera

Now the title might not be able to express the entirety of the question but here's my problem. In my main scene I have a camera and a canvas in overlay mode, let's call this "View A". In this view is a crosshair which position and size I want to manipulate depending on elements inside the canvas of "View B". "View B" is located in the main scene as a render texture it contains a camera and a canvas in camera space with another crosshair. Now what I want to do is the following: I'm trying to set the position and size of the crosshair in "View A" to practically overlap with the values of the crosshair in "View B", i.e. if the crosshair in "View B" is in the lower left corner of its screen I'd like the crosshair in "View A" to be in the same position with the same size but in the canvas of "View A".

[image]

What I'm currently capable of is setting the crosshair in "View A" to the same location as the crosshair in "View B" but only if the crosshair in "View B" is in its origin, as all I have to do in that case is to get the origin of the render texture quad in the screen space of "View A" canvas. I do this in the following way:

```
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(CanvasTransform, CameraComponent.WorldToScreenPoint(RenderTextureQuadTransform.position), null, out Vector2 localPoint);
CursorTransform.localPosition = localPoint;
```

But now I'm stuck in figuring out how to get a scale factor that makes the crosshair in "View A" and "View B" look the same size and how to adjust the position of the crosshair in "View A" depending on the position of the crosshair in "View B".